# How to explain the patterns formed in a resonance experiment?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation

I came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvJAgrUBF4w) on YouTube. Here is an image from this video:

[image]

In this experiment, sand is scattered on a vibrating surface and one can see some beautiful patterns being formed. I think this happens when the surface is in a normal mode

$$u_n(x,y,t) = v_{n}(x,y)\phi_n(t)$$

where $u(x,y,t)$ is the deplacement of the surface at point $(x,y)$ and time $t$. $v_n$ must obey the Hemholtz equation $\Delta v_n = \lambda_n v$ and the pattern we see is the set $\{(x,y): v_n(x,y) = 0\}$.

The problem is that I don't know how to choose an appropriate boundary condition to solve $v_n$.

Can any one suggest a solution? If possible, please plot the curves to see if they look like ones in the video. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is called a Chladni plate, and there is a [comprehensive explanation of it on the physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90021/300).

Comment: Voting to close as belonging on physics.  If it gets moved there it will be a duplicate of the one Rahul cited.